# Blazor webassemblyアプリをIISの[アプリケーションの追加]で追加する方法

Tags: iis, webassembly

Blazor webassemblyをVS2019のテンプレートを使ってHello, world!が表示するWebアプリを作成しています。
Webアプリをiisの[アプリケーションの追加]でWebアプリケーションとして追加をしたいですが、「Loading... An unhandled error has occurred. Reload」と表示されて動きません。
[Webサイトの追加]から追加するとHello, world!が表示されます。
[アプリケーションの追加]でBlazor webassemblyアプリを動作させる方法を知っていれば教えて下さい。

Comment: もしかしたらこれらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[In Blazor WebAssembly solution, how to host the Blazor WASM client app on a different port to the server API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61120227/9014308), [I can't execute a website using blazor webassembly published on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62718995/9014308), [How do I Insert a Blazor WebAssembly App into ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66878219/9014308), [Blazor WebAssembly を触る](https://blog.kondoumh.com/entry/2020/06/19/083350), [ASP.NET Core Blazor のホスティング モデル](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: ちなみにこちらの記事 [IIS で Web サイトの追加](https://creativeweb.jp/personal-site/web-site/), [IIS でアプリケーション（仮想ディレクトリ）の追加](https://creativeweb.jp/personal-site/application/) に操作の違いが図に出ているようですが、そういう操作対象や手順の違いが設定に必要な情報の違いになっているのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。
base hrefを編集したらアプリケーション追加でも動作しました。
助かりました。

Comment: なるべくできれば情報共有のために、どんな違い等があって、何処をどう設定したら動作するようになった等を自己回答してみてください。